# What is the R equivalent to Python's `sns.heatmap(DATANAME.isnull(),cbar=False,cmap='viridis')`?

Tags: python, r

What is the R equivalent to Python's `sns.heatmap(DATANAME.isnull(),cbar=False,cmap='viridis')`? I'd like to make a seaborn style headmap to visualize missing values, but I am using R instead of Python. Thanks!

Comment: There are more people who know R than who know both Python and R, so you might get more/better/faster help if you can describe what  output you want. The `naniar` package offers some visualizations of missing values, btw.

Comment: Thank you, @JonSpring. I wasn't aware of `naniar`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a heatmap of your data where you can easily spot missing values, the default `heatmap()` function might suit. The documentation for this function actually warns you about how bad the default color scheme is. From `?heatmap`:

> The default colors are not pretty. Consider using enhancements such as the RColorBrewer package.

Since you wanted to use the `viridis` palette, I added that from the {viridis} package, which is a great alternative to the default.

```r
# make matrix of sample data
m <- as.matrix(mtcars)
# add missing values
m[sample(1:length(m), 25)] <- NA
# plot heatmap with missing values
heatmap(m, scale = "column", col = viridis::viridis(50))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, @Dan Adams, for your helpful reply. Cheers!